# Disable source parameter on links

Tags: sharepoint, designer

Brief description of the default behavior i want to override:
Creating a SharePoint list and using the "Title (linked to Item)" in a view provides a link to the DispForm for that list.  By default, this link appends a Source parameter to the URL query string.

I would like to disable this behavior in some way while still retaining the default list view web part that is created by SharePoint when the view is defined.

To be clear, I know how to convert the list-view webpart to XSLT and then control this behavior.  If at all possible, I'd like to keep from doing that so that the list view can still be easily supported by Help Desk and also keep the benefits of the standard list view (such as exporting to excel and so forth).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Troy

Comment: Are you averse to using a Javascript/jQuery solution?

Comment: Not at all.  Prefer Javascript, but open to either.

Comment: Based on how SharePoint is adding the parameter, I've suggested a different solution. It still involves Javascript, but in a different way than I had anticipated. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint (2007) dynamically appends the `source` parameter in a javascript method named `GoToLink`. That method is defined in SharePoint's **core.js** file, and it can be easily customized without editing the original file. In fact, you never want to edit that file directly; it will put SharePoint into an "unsupported" state.

We'll create a solution for our customization, so it can easily be deployed or retracted in a consistent manner. Create a new Empty SharePoint solution in Visual Studio, targeted for GAC deployment. Within your project, create the following folder structure:

- Templates

  - Layouts

    - 1033

("1033" is for the English localization; if you're using a different language, your id will be different).

Within "1033", create a new Javascript file (we call our ours "CustomCore.js"). This will contain JUST the code we want to override from Core.js. Since GoToLink is the only thing we're interested in, let's focus on that. Here's the original from Core.js:

```
function GoToLink(elm) {
    if (elm.href==null)
      return;
    var ch=elm.href.indexOf("?") >=0 ? "&" : "?";
    var srcUrl=GetSource();
    if (srcUrl !=null && srcUrl !="")
      srcUrl=ch+"Source="+srcUrl;
    var targetUrl=elm.href+srcUrl;
    if (isPortalTemplatePage(targetUrl))
      window.top.location=STSPageUrlValidation(targetUrl);
    else
      window.location=STSPageUrlValidation(targetUrl);
}
```

Not much to it. For our override, we just need to omit the bits that add the `source` parameter. From my reckoning, the modified method looks like this:

```
function GoToLink(elm) {
    if (elm.href==null)
        return;
    if (isPortalTemplatePage(elm.href))
        window.top.location=STSPageUrlValidation(elm.href);
    else
        window.location=STSPageUrlValidation(elm.href);
}
```

That should be it. Package up the solution and Visual Studio should interpret the "Templates" folder structure correctly when it builds the WSP (look in the generated manifest file for the `TemplateFile` element and that it's deploying to "Layouts\1033\CustomCore.js").

Once your WSP solution is deployed to SharePoint, we have the final step of referencing it in your Master page. In the `HEAD` section of your master page, you should see Core.js being referenced like this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" runat="server" Defer="True" Name="core.js"/>
```

We simply add a reference to the new JS file directly beneath this line:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" runat="server" Defer="True" Name="core.js"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" runat="server" Defer="True" Name="customcore.js"/>
```

Test it out and make sure it works. Note that this will affect ALL lists on the server to which you've deployed "CustomCore.js" and which use the master page.

Comment: Fantastic information.  Thanks!  Affecting links on all sites is not really an option for me, but this information is definitely a step in the right direction.  We use a custom master page and If this issue becomes big enough, I could make the case of having a second master page just for this issue.  I'll continue to play around with this and see where I can get.  Thanks again.